# Convert CDF $F$ to $G $ defined by $G(x) = P(X<x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a r.v. whose possible values are $0, 1, 2,... ,$ with CDF $F$. In some
countries, rather than using a CDF, the convention is to use the function $G $defined
by $G(x) = P(X<x)$ to specify a distribution. Find a way to convert from F to G,
*i.e.*, if F is a known function show how to obtain $G(x)$ for all real $x$.

**Answer**

First

$G(x) = P(X \le x)  - P(X = x) = F(x) - P(X = x)$

If $x$ is not a nonnegative integer, then $P(X = x) = 0 $ so $ G(x) = F(x)$.

*(first, wouldn't $P(X \le x)$ also be equal to 0, so G(x) = F(x) = 0 anyways? Otherwise I understand up until this part, but I would appreciate help understanding the rest of this answer)*

For $x$ a
nonnegative integer,
$P(X = x) = F(x) - F(x - 1/2)$
since the PMF corresponds to the lengths of the jumps in the CDF. (The 1/2 was
chosen for concreteness; we also have $F(x - 1/2) = F(x - a)$ for any $a \in (0, 1]$.)

$$G(x) = \begin{cases}
  F(x), & \text{if } x \not\in \{0, 1, 2,... \}\\
  F(x - 1/2), & \text{if } x \in \{0, 1, 2,... \}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$G(x)=F(x^-):=\lim_{y\to x,\ y\lt x}F(y)$$

Answer (score 0):

$G\left ( x \right ) = P\left ( X< x \right ) = P \left ( X \leq  x - 1 \right ) \forall x \in \mathbb{N}
\rightarrow  F\left ( x - 1 \right )$